# Css3 - first-child and last-child selector issues

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble coding my first and last child selectors.

Firstly I would like to remove the right border off the last child of the parent navigation menu only (not the drop down menus), my current code is affecting the drop down menu also. I am having the same issue with removing the left border off the first child.

Secondly, I wanted to add a box shadow to the left and right of the parent navigation menu, but this is also impacting on the drop down menu.

I would appreciate some advice on where i am going wrong. Thanks

My CSS3 code is:

```
 ul#navmenu li:last-child a  {border-right: none;}

 ul#navmenu li:first-child a {border-left: none;}

 ul#navmenu li:last-child {box-shadow: 200px 0px 0px 0px white;}

 ul#navmenu li:first-child {box-shadow:-200px 0px 0px 0px white;}
```

Comment: Can you show me the html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the direct child of the `ul` elements like below using `>` for direct child selector

```
 ul#navmenu > li:last-child a  {border-right: none;}

 ul#navmenu > li:first-child a {border-left: none;}

 ul#navmenu > li:last-child {box-shadow: 200px 0px 0px 0px white;}

 ul#navmenu > li:first-child {box-shadow:-200px 0px 0px 0px white;}
```

Your current selector is `ul#navmenu li` this means to select all the `li` tags that come under the `ul` which can be at any level deep.

But this selector `ul#navmenu > li` restricts the selection to only the **immediate child** of `ul#navmenu` and this **is what you need**.